# Joining as shape breaks model

Tags: vertices, shape-keys

I have this problem where I have two models with the same number of verts and the same UVs and I want to have one of them join the other as a shapekey. The problem is that whenever I do that, A shape key is created, but when I slide it to 1 it totally breaks the model

here's a look at the two heads and the end result.
[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: also if you imported your model make sure the triangulation is the same on both

Comment: I'm pointing to vertex indices, because issue looks very similar https://youtu.be/j6hyEu1r48o?t=129

Answer (score 1):

Check if your vertex indices match on both objects.
To display them enable as *Overlay > Developer > Indices*

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Two other things can break the shape keys - Auto-Smooth seems to need to be set the same in both meshes, and (duh) no deform modifiers on either.